# Swift CoreData FetchRequest - How to extract a value from an entity by using another value

Tags: swift

I have an entity in my CoreData setup that uses two strings: "name" and "stadium".

I'm trying to write a function that takes a "name" as a parameter, does a CoreData fetch and returns the corresponding "stadium" string value for that "name" entity. This seems like it shouldn't be too hard but I don't know where to start...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use `NSPredicate` for filtering.

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Team>(entityName: "Team")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", nameToFind)
fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
let team = (try? context.fetch(fetchRequest))?.first

return team?.stadium
```